# Python dataframe to dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

How can I transform the dataframe below to the dictionary below (keys are all names and values are lists containing the score of each occurrence)?

```
# input:
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':["Adam", "Sarah", "Tom", "Sarah", "Adam", "Tom", "Shara"], 'score':[1,6,2,3,1,9,5]})

# desired output:
my_dict = {"Adam": [1,4], "Sarah":[6,3,5], "Tom":[2,9]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need `groupby`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':["Adam", "Sarah", "Tom", "Sarah", "Adam", "Tom", "Shara"], 'score':[1,6,2,3,1,9,5]})

print(df.groupby('name')['score'].apply(list).to_dict() )
```

**Output:**

```
{'Adam': [1, 1], 'Sarah': [6, 3], 'Shara': [5], 'Tom': [2, 9]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to define an empty dictionay and then add key-value pairs by filtering each key from the Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':["Adam", "Sarah", "Tom", "Sarah", "Adam", "Tom", "Shara"], 'score':[1,6,2,3,1,9,5]})

my_dict = {}
for x in df.name.unique():
    my_dict[x] = df[df.name == x].score.values.tolist()
```

Or in a more efficient way:

```
my_dict = { x : df[df.name == x].score.values.tolist() for x in df.name.unique() }
```